# Partial template instanciation

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

If I have this two template classes:

```
template<int a, typename V>
class A {
};

template<template<int, typename> typename V>
class  B {
};
```

I can write something like `B<A> a;`.
How can I achieve a similar thing for this two classes:

```
template<int a, typename V>
class A {
};

template<template<typename> typename V>
class  B {
};
```

I want to declare a variable like this `B<A<1>> a;`, but it says that A needs 2 parameters, which would be correct for an instance of A, but I only want to create a new template with a smaller number of parameters.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Where do you plan to provide the missing parameter for A? As part of the B declaration?

Comment: With missing parameter you mean the parameter V? Yes, that would be set somewhere in the definition of B, like in there first example.

Comment: I'm confused by what you're trying to do. If you want `B<A<1>>` to work then the second parameter of `A` is either not needed or can be defaulted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this directly, but you can create a helper template `using` and pass it to `B`.

```
template <int N>
struct foo
{
    template <typename T>
    using type = A<N, T>;
};

B<foo<42>::type> x;
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes C++ has two many keywords. I tried the same thing with typedef instead of using, but that's not allowed.

Comment: @gerum Yep. Template typedefs in general are not allowed, but template usings are allowed.

Comment: `typedef` dates back to C and does things C-style to maintain compatibility. Even though it has been supplanted by a more C++-aware alternative, `typedef` is unlikely to be removed from the language any time soon. Too much code depends on it.